# Is there a way to change file metadata (e.g. owner) on Unix platforms with Rust?

Tags: unix, rust

The standard library provides a way to change file permissions, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't think Rust's `std` has a way to change a file owner. But the `libc` crate (https://crates.io/crates/libc) has a `chmod` function.

Comment: I suspect it's not included in `std` because it would have to be platform dependent.

Comment: @PeterHall, is an external library still required?

Comment: @ChrisHappy not if you use Nightly... [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/88989)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some OS specific funtionality can be found in the `std::os` module: for example [`std::os::unix::fs::MetadataExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html) allows to read `uid`/ `guid` or [`std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.PermissionsExt.html) handles file modes. However AFAIK there is no `std` support for changing owner / group.

As [PeterHall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493729/peter-hall) commented, there is a `chmod` (and `chown`) function in the `libc` crate.

For further examples and inspiration, I suggest you to have a look to the [coreutils](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils) project that implements many common GNU CLI utils, among which you can find the metadata manipulation ones.